# How to add a child element to a parent but only if it's not there already?

Tags: angularjs

When I add some `<div>` of "GrainContenu" into a `<div>` of division, all the future additions to `<div>` division keep multiples of `<div>` "GrainContenu".

```js
angular.module("Webapp",[])
    .controller("WebCtrl",function($scope){
 
 //new division
 $scope.divisions = [{id: 'division1'}];
 
 $scope.addNewDivision = function() {
   var newItemNo = $scope.divisions.length+1;
   $scope.divisions.push({'id':'division'+newItemNo});
   console.log($scope.divisions[0]);
 };

 //new grainContenu
 $scope.grainContenus = [{id: 'grainContenu1'}];
 
 $scope.addNewGrainContenu = function() {
   var newItemNo = $scope.grainContenus.length+1;
   $scope.grainContenus.push({'id':'grainContenu'+newItemNo});
 };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  
<body ng-app="Webapp" ng-controller="WebCtrl">

 
 <h1>Module Opale</h1>
 Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
   Metadonnées<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
   Objectif du module <input type="text" placeholder="Objectif">

 <div class="form-group"  data-ng-repeat="division in divisions">
    <h2><a ng-click="addNewDivision()">*</a>Division</h2>
    Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
    Titre court<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />

      <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="grainContenu in grainContenus">
       <h3><a ng-click="addNewGrainContenu()">*</a>Grain de Contenu</h3>
    Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
      Titre court<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />

      <h4>Information</h4>
      Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br />
   </div>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is using a nested controller.

```js
angular.module("Webapp", [])
  .controller("WebCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.divisions = [{id: 'division1'}];
    $scope.addNewDivision = function() {
      $scope.divisions.push({id: 'division' + ($scope.divisions.length+1)});
      console.log($scope.divisions);
    };
  })
  .controller('divisionController', function($scope) {
    $scope.grainContenus = [{'id': 'grainContenu1'}];
    $scope.addNewGrainContenu = function() {
      $scope.grainContenus.push({'id': 'grainContenu' + ($scope.grainContenus.length+1)});
      console.log($scope.grainContenus);
    };
  });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="Webapp" ng-controller="WebCtrl">
  <h1>Module Opale</h1>
  Titre
  <input type="text" placeholder="Titre">
  <br />Metadonnées
  <input type="text" placeholder="Titre">
  <br />Objectif du module
  <input type="text" placeholder="Objectif">

  <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="division in divisions" ng-controller='divisionController'>
    <h2><a ng-click="addNewDivision()">*</a>Division</h2>
    Titre
    <input type="text" placeholder="Titre">
    <br />Titre court
    <input type="text" placeholder="Titre">
    <br />

    <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="grainContenu in grainContenus">
      <h3><a ng-click="addNewGrainContenu()">*</a>Grain de Contenu</h3>
      Titre
      <input type="text" placeholder="Titre">
      <br />Titre court
      <input type="text" placeholder="Titre">
      <br />

      <h4>Information</h4>
      Titre
      <input type="text" placeholder="Titre">
      <br />
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, tkank u for ur help...(((y)

Comment: How can I add more than "division" or "GrainContenu" into GrainContenu otherwise, each "GrainContenu" can contain many "Division"

Answer (score 1):

Only thing i can understand from your code is that once user clicks on the any of the headers (*Division and Grain de Contenu) only div in belonging to that header should get added, I have modified your code so that it works the way you want.

```js
angular.module("Webapp",[])
    .controller("WebCtrl",function($scope){
 
 //new division
 $scope.divisions = [{id: 'division1'}];
 
 $scope.addNewDivision = function() {
   var newItemNo = $scope.divisions.length+1;
   $scope.divisions.push({'id':'division'+newItemNo});
   console.log($scope.divisions[0]);
 };


 

 //new grainContenu
 $scope.grainContenus = [{id: 'grainContenu1'}];
 
 $scope.addNewGrainContenu = function() {
   var newItemNo = $scope.grainContenus.length+1;
   $scope.grainContenus.push({'id':'grainContenu'+newItemNo});
 };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  
<body ng-app="Webapp" ng-controller="WebCtrl">

 
 <h1>Module Opale</h1>
 Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
   Metadonnées<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
   Objectif du module <input type="text" placeholder="Objectif">

 <div class="form-group"  data-ng-repeat="division in divisions">
    <h2><a ng-click="addNewDivision()">*</a>Division</h2>
    Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
    Titre court<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
       </div> 
      <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="grainContenu in grainContenus">
       <h3><a ng-click="addNewGrainContenu()">*</a>Grain de Contenu</h3>
    Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
      Titre court<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
        </div>
      <h4>Information</h4>
      Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br />
   
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good Morning, thanks for your answer, I tried what you suggesed for me, but the the  <div>"GrainContenu" is included into <div>Division at least ones,